# How to execute code "before_serialize"? or How can I sanitize attributes before they are serialized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, callback

I am following this pattern to ensure all my attributes are normalized before they are saved:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :normalize_attributes

  def normalize_attributes
    self.name&.strip!
    self.email&.strip!
  end
end
```

I have also some others more complicated:

```
def normalize_attributes
  # Transform to array if it is a string with things
  # separated by comas
  if self.favorite_things.is_a? String
    self.favorite_things = self.favorite_things.split(",").map(&:strip)
  end
end
```

It works, but the problem is that when I add this attribute to the `serialized` ones it fails:

```
serialize :favorite_things, Array
```

Like in here:

```
my_model.update(favorite_things: "ONE, TWO, THREE")
```

The error:

```
Error:
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: can't serialize `favorite_things`: was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "ONE, TWO, THREE"
```

It looks like the `serialize` command is executed before the `before_validation`.

How can I sanitize attributes before they are serialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure all your attributes are normalized before saving - overwrite setters:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  # @param value [String]
  # @return [String]
  def name=(value)
    super(value.strip)
  end
  
  # @param value [String]
  # @return [String]
  def email=(value)
    super(value.strip)
  end
  
  # @param value [String, Array]
  # @return [Array]
  def favorite_things=(value)
    return super(value) unless value.is_a? String
    
    super(favorite_things.split(",").map(&:strip))
  end
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Overwriting+default+accessors

Comment: Yes, it is what I was looking to do. I liked more the idea of having all _normalizations_ together in the same method. But looks like this is the only option that works with `serialize`